# Why do we allow downvotes on first posts?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, new-users

One of the things that really irks me about parts of the SO community is the downvoting patterns. A good example of this is downvoting users first posts. I stumbled on this question today: [Why can't I get my script tag src's to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43174018/why-cant-i-get-my-script-tag-srcs-to-work) (I know, feel free to remove for link for the sake of meta effect if necessary). I had the same question about a much higher quality post [Appending Values to List Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129573/appending-values-to-list-python/) the other day (where I simply commented on the OP).

The question is not the ideal SO question but it's also a question in which the user has explained enough of the problem that it's easy to see what's wrong (IMHO). Yet, it has 3 downvotes in 10 minutes on a weekend.

It seems to me that allowing downvotes on a first post (specifically when there are no upvotes is a surefire way to discourage new users).

Comment: I'm afraid at 12,000+ new incoming questions every day, quality control is more important than not discouraging new users.

Comment: What does down voting first posts accomplish?

Comment: The same as downvoting any post with problems accomplishes: it sends a signal to the user that there is a problem; and it helps the site's quality control mechanisms in various ways (negatively voted questions with no answers are eventually deleted, and users with consistently negatively voted questions will eventually be banned from asking more, a *vital* part of keeping the site sane.)

Comment: ... I don't disagree SO can be a harsh and arcane place for new users, and that it would be much better if it weren't. But disallowing downvotes on first posts would just very imperfectly cure a symptom, nothing more. The reality is SO sets a higher bar than some of its marketing copy suggests. You are expected to already be able to think and provide details like a developer.

Comment: @Pekka웃 actually, I feel like it would be several times worse. It could make users do draconian stuff like editing their first question over and over whenever they have a new issue.

Comment: For eff's sake, stop trying to weaken downvotes even further! They're already too weak to make an actual dent in the pile of crap called "three fourths or so of all Stack Overflow questions"!

Comment: This would make it impossible to find genuinely good questions because there's no way to filter first posts out. Alternatively, it'd drastically reduce the chance of getting good answers if such a filter was added. You'd essentially be fulfilling that recurring feature request to be able to filter questions by the rep of the user posting it. So either we lie to the community about the quality of questions or we ensure that first questions never get seen by the more knowledgeable users here.

Comment: People are negative by design.

Comment: Simpe. To learn and to improve from the next post onwards.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ The fact that there are 10x more upvotes than downvotes begs to differ.

Answer (score 35):

If a question is bad it deserves downvotes.

It shouldn't and doesn't matter whether it's a first question or a question of a user with 25k+ reputation points. Questions and answers should be evaluated by their content, not by the fact by whom they are posted.

It ensures quality control on Stack Overflow and every other Stack Exchange site. Not downvoting might send the wrong message to the new user - that such questions are acceptable here.

Stack Overflow needs more *quality* content (both questions and answers), keeping low quality content serves little to no purpose. It only drives the experts away without attracting new ones.

Comment: isn't a first post approved by the community?

Comment: @Kerooker approved? Do you know that the median time a reviewer spends reviewing first posts is little over 3 seconds, and the button isn't enabled for the first two?

Comment: @Kerooker No. There is a first post review queue, but one of the actions you can take there is up- or downvote the question (or VTC etc).

Comment: @Braiam Then maybe the system should be better for that, but if it's reviewed and not closed as an unclear answer, it should be a correct post

Comment: @Kerooker "better for" what exactly? Before the "No action needed" button, people just upvoted *every* post to enable the "I'm done" button and get their next review. There's no much you can do with the system, if the people that are supposed to use it don't care what is meant to do.

Comment: @Kerooker Just because a question wasnt closed does not mean it does not deserve a downvte. Close Votes are not "super-downvotes" and should not be used or be treated as such. Just because there is no reason to close the question outright does not mean there is no reason to downvote. By your logic SO could replace downvotes with closevotes on questions complete - which isn't going to happen.

Comment: @Kerooker Users' first posts aren't approved by the community.  *Some* users' first posts have extra attention given to them.  There is no "approval" or "denial" of the posts from the queue.

Comment: @Servy even though there _should_ be.

Comment: @TinyGiant There's no possible way that there *could* be.  There are nowhere near enough suitable reviewers to handle all of the questions posted, even if you use all of the filters that FP already uses (and even with all its doing now posts aren't typically reviewed in a timely fashion, and are currently only reviewed by a single person, which wouldn't really be an option if the review determined if the post is actually posted in the first place)..

Comment: @Servy I realize that it isn't possible at this scale, but that doesn't stop me from dreaming.